# STL map and pure virtual base class

Tags: c++, stl, virtual, abstract-base-class

I have not used C++ in a long time. I'm trying to display some polymorphic behavior:

```
class func {
    public:
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class func1 : public func {
    public:
    void print () { cout << "FUNC 1" << endl; };
};

class func2 : public func {
   public:
     void print () { cout << "FUNC 2" << endl; };
};


static map<string,func *> myMap;
static func1 f1 = func1 ();
static func2 f2 = func2 ();
myMap["func1"] = &f1;
myMap["func2"] = &f2;
```

So In my main function, when I call:

```
myMap["func1"]->print();
myMap["func2"]->print();
```

I would expect:

```
FUNC 1
FUNC 2
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do this. When I compile the code, it gives me this error:

```
test.cc:31: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
test.cc:32: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘=’ token
```

Which refers to these lines:

```
myMap["func1"] = &f1;
myMap["func2"] = &f2;
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do these statements `myMap["func1"] = &f1;`, `myMap["func2"] = &f2;` appear outside a function definition body?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ most probably they are.

Comment: Yes they are. I see, now my code compiles. Why do they have to be inside a function definition?

Comment: `static func1 f1 = func1 ();` should be `static func1 f1;`

Comment: @Neil Kirk: It is completely irerlevant. And no, it "shoudn't" be that. If the OP prefers this form specific form, he's free to use it.

Comment: @SquallLeohart That's something to reference from the C/C++ standard.  Mike's answer gives more insight on this.

Comment: @SquallLeohart See Mike Seymour's answer. It explains the available options  for initialization quite well.

Comment: @Squall Leohart: In C++ language (as well as in C) all *statements* have to reside inside function definitions. That is what an actual program in C++ is: a bunch of statements inside functions. All you can do outside of functions is write *declarations*.

Comment: @NeilKirk Isn't `static func1 f1 = func1 ();` legitimate C++ code?

Comment: Ok ok it is legitimate code and not the cause of the error. But still, I'm pointing out to the OP that you don't have to initialize them that way. He might not know.

Comment: I knew, I was just being lazy changing from static 
   func1 *f1 = new func1(); 
but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expression statements, like those assignment statements, can only go inside functions.

In C++11, you can initialise the static map using brace-initialisation:

```
static map<string,func *> myMap = {
    {"func1", &f1},
    {"func2", &f2}
};
```

If you're stuck in the past, then either populate it in a function (perhaps `main`, or something you call before doing anything with the map), or write a function to return a populated map:

```
std::map<string,func*> make_map() {
    std::map<string,func*> map;
    map["func1"] = &f1;
    map["func2"] = &f2;
    return map;
}

static std::map<string,func *> myMap = make_map();
```

A better idea might be to avoid non-trivial global variables, if possible; they often bring a world of pain.